# WHMCS PHP Sessions Not working

Tags: php, session, debian, whmcs

My WHMCS installation suddenly stopped working two days ago. I can access the client area, but can't login... after I input the correct details, the browser keeps trying to load a page but no page ever loads. I created a test file and confirmed it an issue with PHP sessions. Seeing as it's probably not the script, since WHMCS is a widely-used and tested software, I'm trying to figure out what possible configurations could cause php sessions to not work. /tmp is writable, and I set the directory specified in php.in, session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session" to 777 permissions. I read somehwere that the session.save_path folder should NOT be under the user control of root; mine is. What should I set it to? I have no other users. In the gc.compatibility was 1 and I set it to 0, and restarted httpd, but still can't login. 
Here's the phpinfo:

```
http://192.155.82.64/clients/phpinfo.php
```

This is running on the latest Debian distro. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Cloudflare? If so, make sure to set your firewall to LOW.

Or, go WHMCS Setup  > Security and check Disable Session IP Check.

After checking the WHMCS admin log i noticed i was logging in from Cloudflare ips and every time the ip changed, i got logout.

Comment: This can be fixed permanently by changing the Proxy IP Header setting under the Security tab in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, and the culprit was `session.auto_start` being enabled. After disabling it, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your session directory (/var/lib/php/session) should NOT be set to the root user. It needs to be set to the user and group that runs Apache (sometimes its apache, or nobody). You can check if the directory is the problem by locating the PHPSESSID cookie value and see if a file is created in the session directory. You can try asking WHMCS about this but they may charge you for their time.

Comment: How would I locate the phpsessid cookie value?

Comment: Also, could you direct me to the process for changing the user? I'm using WinSCP GUI and I don't have an option to change the directory to anything other than root (in the drop-down list only root is available).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and fixed it by disabling `zlib.output_compression` in my `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

So figured I would chime in since I was having this problem.

Specifically, for Cloudflare. I had to add their IPs to WHMCS as Trusted Proxies
**System Settings** > **General Settings** > **Security Tab**.

In the **Trusted Proxies** list, I put all of the **CIDR** **IPs** from **Cloudflare**'s own website.

https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

After that, I changed the "**Proxy IP Header**" to "**X_FORWARDED_FOR**".

Seems to be working now. I originally was getting logged out every 2 minutes or so. If that.

I hope this helps someone as I spent a while trying to find an answer.

***Also, quickly add those IPs because you might get timed out before finishing. Just log back in and repeat as quickly as possible. Once you hit "Add" and save the IP it actually saves right then. Even though you didn't click the save button at the bottom of the "**Security Tab**"***

Comment: we had CF-Connecting-IP as per CF's documentation ... changing to X_FORWARDED_FOR fixed it...

Answer (score -1):

Check your `.htaccess` file and rename it to something like `.htaccess2` just to make sure that's not messing with it.

You could have PHP configuration set in this file that may be causing issues, by setting session configuration, parameters, etc.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why should that file interfere when there is "an issue with PHP sessions"?